# JavaFX - create a Windows application type (maximize, minimize).

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

In Java "SE", easily using Swing, graphically, I can create a JFrame, add in a JDesktoPane, and use a JInternalFrame to create a Windows application type (maximize, minimize, etc.) inside the JFrame.How I can do it in JavaFX? thanks for the comments!

PD. I'm using escene Builder to build the GUI in JavaFX, I do not know how to combine the components to achieve something like Swing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Design your application GUI in SceneBuilder, every `Node` (graphical element) which you want to control, manage or just program should be getting an *id* which will be set on the Code area on right.
2. Then go to the SampleController class and instantiate any Node which got a code with a @FXML annotation prefix.
3. Create methods with the @FXML annotation prefix which may receive as argument either an `ActionEvent`, `MouseEvent` or `KeyboardEvent`.
4. In SceneBuilder, associate for any Node, a custom event with any of the methods you created.